# SQL Create Identity Column Based On Other Table Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql Server 2017

Is it possible to construct a column in SQL that acts as an Identity column for a clustered Primary Key (Value1, Value2, Value3)?

```
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Identity-ish? |
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 1             |
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 2             |
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
| 1      | 2      | 1      | 1             |
| 1      | 2      | 1      | 2             |
| 1      | 2      | 1      | 3             |
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
| 2      | 5      | 3      | 1             |
| 2      | 5      | 3      | 2             |
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
| 82     | 21     | 13     | 1             |
| 82     | 21     | 13     | 2             |
|--------+--------+--------+---------------|
```

Currently the way I am tackling this issue is by querying the table for the max(Identity-ish?) on a given PK, and incrementing it when inserting a new record.

However, the scale of the project has reached such a size where this method is getting called too frequently, and sometimes it gets called twice at the same time (causing two identical rows (Value1, Value2, Value3, Identity-ish?))

Ideally I would like to be able to declare Identity-ish? as an Identity column that gets its' values automatically assigned in the way I've shown above.

Comment: You could use ROW_NUMBER with a partition. And when you start naming things "ish" you know you are a bit off track. Nothing in the database is a kinda sortof. :)

Comment: I was hoping there was a name for the `ish` that I just wasn't aware of. Some way of clustering an Identity Column for example.

Comment: To cluster an identity column would mean the identity column is the clustered index. What you have is nothing like an identity because it requires partitioning on groups.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is I think:

```
select * from
(
select Value1,Value2,Value3,
row_number ()over (partition by Value1,Value2,Value3 order by
Value1,Value2,Value3) as  Identity-ish?
from tablename
)rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `ROW_NUMBER()`function with partition for column

```
select t.*,
ROW_NUMBER()
OVER(partition by value1,value2,value3 ORDER BY value1,value2,value3 )
   from t

value1  value2  value3  identity_is
1        1           1         1
1        1           1         2
1        2           1          1
1        2           1          2
1        2          1            3
```

here i put an example

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4b62/4

Comment: Does this work even if I want to delete a row? i.e. will the deleted `identity_is` value be re-used?